# A record showing wrong IP address on DNS lookup for my domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

Hi I have registered a domain qualebs.com on godaddy.com
It has been working well for 2years now. Today I made a payment for its renewal. Since then I have not been able to access my website. Any attempt leaves me with the dreaded vague godaddy messages `This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.`

I have my A record pointing to my VS ip address hosted at eapps.com
I don't know what to do and unfortunately customer care for godaddy is always offline please help

Answer (score 2):

There are two A records for your domain.

```
qualebs.com has address 209.10.74.11
qualebs.com has address 184.168.221.18
```

One of them kind of works if I connect to the IP directly (209.10.74.11), the other generates the error you observe (184.168.221.18). The first one appears to belong to EApps, so I guess this is the correct one. Check your domain records in the web interface and remove the offending address. After the DNS caches have expired, everything should be working again.

If you don't see the erroneous record in your domain entries, you need to contact GoDaddy support because there is nothing we could do to help you.